# (Swift) How to check if content-encoding is gzip

Tags: swift, http, gzip

Is there any way in Swift to find out if data from a request returns in gzip?

I want to write a test method to check if Content-Encoding returns gzip file:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get this info from the header fields in the `HTTPURLResponse`:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if let encoding = response.allHeaderFields["Content-Encoding"] as? String {
            print(encoding)
            print(encoding == "gzip")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Note that this downloads the headers *and* the data.

If you want to only get the headers without downloading the data, a better solution is to use an `URLRequest` set to `"HEAD"` like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (_, response, _) in
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if let enc = response.allHeaderFields["Content-Encoding"] as? String {
            print(enc)
            print(enc == "gzip")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

This way, only the headers are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the first 4 bytes of the file, you should get a [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files)

So you should be able to do something like:

```
var magicNumber = [UInt](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0)
data.getBytes(&magicNumber, length: 4 * sizeof(UInt))
```

If it's GZipped, it will have a Magic Number of 1f 8b, so check for that.